# gRPC throws Exception: Direct self-reference leading to cycle

Tags: jackson, microservices, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am using GRPC to communicate between two microservices .I am converting DTO class to proto enerated class but code is throwing exception. Below is my code of .proto file

schema.proto

```
syntax="proto3";
option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package="com.abc.xyz";
import "google/type/date.proto";

message BanksData {
    string bankCode= 1;
    string previousWorkingDate= 2;
    string presentWorkingDate= 3;
    string nextWorkingDate= 4;
}

message BanksDataRequest{

}


message BanksDataResponse{
  repeated BanksData banksDataGrpcDTO= 1;
}

service BanksDataService{
  rpc getAllBanksData(BanksDataRequest) returns (BanksDataResponse);
  rpc deleteAllBanksData(BanksDataRequest) returns (BanksDataResponse);
}
```

BanksDataEntity.java

```
package com.abc.xyz.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import lombok.*;


import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.security.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;


@Table(name="banks_data")
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class BanksDataEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="bank_code")
    @JsonProperty("bank_code")
    private String bankCode;

    @Column(name = "previous_working_date")
    @JsonProperty("previous_working_date")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date previousWorkingDate;
    @Column(name = "present_working_date")
    @JsonProperty("present_working_date")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date presentWorkingDate;
    @Column(name = "next_working_date")
    @JsonProperty("next_working_date")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date nextWorkingDate;


    public String getBankCode() {
        return bankCode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BanksDataEntity{" +
                "bankCode='" + bankCode + '\'' +
                ", previousWorkingDate=" + previousWorkingDate +
                ", presentWorkingDate=" + presentWorkingDate +
                ", nextWorkingDate=" + nextWorkingDate +
                '}';
    }

    public void setBankCode(String bankCode) {
        this.bankCode = bankCode;
    }

    public Date getPreviousWorkingDate() {
        return previousWorkingDate;
    }

    public void setPreviousWorkingDate(Date previousWorkingDate) {
        this.previousWorkingDate = previousWorkingDate;
    }

    public Date getPresentWorkingDate() {
        return presentWorkingDate;
    }

    public void setPresentWorkingDate(Date presentWorkingDate) {
        this.presentWorkingDate = presentWorkingDate;
    }

    public Date getNextWorkingDate() {
        return nextWorkingDate;
    }

    public void setNextWorkingDate(Date nextWorkingDate) {
        this.nextWorkingDate = nextWorkingDate;
    }
}
```

BanksDataDTO.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.*;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.security.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;


@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class BanksDataDTO implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @JsonProperty("bank_code")
    private String bankCode;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @JsonProperty("previous_working_date")
    private Date previousWorkingDate;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @JsonProperty("present_working_date")
    private Date presentWorkingDate;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @JsonProperty("next_working_date")
    private Date nextWorkingDate;

    public String getBankCode() {
        return bankCode;
    }

    public void setBankCode(String bankCode) {
        this.bankCode = bankCode;
    }

    public Date getPreviousWorkingDate() {
        return previousWorkingDate;
    }

    public void setPreviousWorkingDate(Date previousWorkingDate) {
        this.previousWorkingDate = previousWorkingDate;
    }

    public Date getPresentWorkingDate() {
        return presentWorkingDate;
    }

    public void setPresentWorkingDate(Date presentWorkingDate) {
        this.presentWorkingDate = presentWorkingDate;
    }

    public Date getNextWorkingDate() {
        return nextWorkingDate;
    }

    public void setNextWorkingDate(Date nextWorkingDate) {
        this.nextWorkingDate = nextWorkingDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BanksDataDTO{" +
                "bankCode='" + bankCode + '\'' +
                ", previousWorkingDate=" + previousWorkingDate +
                ", presentWorkingDate=" + presentWorkingDate +
                ", nextWorkingDate=" + nextWorkingDate +
                '}';
    }
}
```

BanksDataGrpcServiceImpl.java

```
import io.grpc.stub.StreamObserver;
import net.devh.boot.grpc.server.service.GrpcService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.util.List;

@GrpcService
public class BanksDataGrpcServiceImpl  extends BanksDataServiceGrpc.BanksDataServiceImplBase {

    @Autowired
    private BanksDataRepository banksDataRepository;
    @Autowired
    private BanksDataMapper banksDataMapper;
    public void getAllBanksData(BanksDataRequest request, StreamObserver<BanksDataResponse> responseObserver) {
        System.out.println(" : BanksDataGrpcServiceImpl : getAllBanksData : Method starts");

        List<BanksDataEntity>  banksDataEntityList = banksDataRepository.findAll();
        List<BanksData> banksDataList = banksDataMapper.entityListToGrpcList(banksDataEntityList);
        BanksDataResponse banksDataResponse = BanksDataResponse.newBuilder().addAllBanksDataGrpcDTO(banksDataList).build();
        responseObserver.onNext(banksDataResponse);
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }

}
```

BanksDataMapper.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

import org.mapstruct.*;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",
        collectionMappingStrategy = CollectionMappingStrategy.ADDER_PREFERRED,
        nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS,
        unmappedSourcePolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE,
        unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface BanksDataMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "bank_code",target = "bank_code")
    @Mapping(target = "previous_working_date",expression = "java(toJavaDate(banksGrpcList.getPreviousWorkingDate()))")
    @Mapping(target = "present_working_date",expression = "java(toJavaDate(banksGrpcList.getPresentWorkingDate())))")
    @Mapping(target = "next_working_date",expression = "java(toJavaDate(banksGrpcList.getNextWorkingDate())))")
    List<BanksDataEntity> grpcListToEntityList (List<BanksData> banksGrpcList);
/*
    @Mapping(source = "bank_code",target = "bank_code")
    @Mapping(target = "previous_working_date",expression = "java(toProtoDate(entityList.getPreviousWorkingDate()))")
    @Mapping(target = "present_working_date",expression = "java(toProtoDate(entityList.getPresentWorkingDate())))")
    @Mapping(target = "next_working_date",expression = "java(toProtoDate(entityList.getNextWorkingDate())))")
//    @Mapping(target = "previous_working_date",expression = "java(entityList.getPreviousWorkingDate().stream().forEachOrdered(previousWorkingDate -> toProtoDate(previousWorkingDate) ))")
//    @Mapping(target = "present_working_date",expression = "java(entityList.getPresentWorkingDate().stream().forEachOrdered(presentWorkingDate -> toProtoDate(presentWorkingDate) ))")
//    @Mapping(target = "next_working_date",expression = "java(entityList.getNextWorkingDate().stream().forEachOrdered(nextWorkingDate -> toProtoDate(nextWorkingDate) ))")
    List<BanksData> entityListToGrpcList (List<BanksDataEntity> entityList);

 */

    @Mapping(source = "bank_code",target = "bank_code")
    @Mapping(target = "previous_working_date",expression = "java(toStringDate(entityList.getPreviousWorkingDate()))")
    @Mapping(target = "present_working_date",expression = "java(toStringDate(entityList.getPresentWorkingDate())))")
    @Mapping(target = "next_working_date",expression = "java(toStringDate(entityList.getNextWorkingDate())))")
    List<BanksData> entityListToGrpcList (List<BanksDataEntity> entityList);

    public default String  toStringDate(Date javaDate) {
        Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String strDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        return strDate;
    }
    public default com.google.type.Date toProtoDate(Date javaDate) {
        Instant instant = javaDate.toInstant();
        LocalDate localDate = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        return com.google.type.Date.newBuilder()
                .setYear(localDate.getYear())
                .setMonth(localDate.getMonthValue())
                .setDay(localDate.getDayOfMonth())
                .build();
    }
    public default Date toJavaDate(com.google.type.Date date) {
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDay());
        return Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    }
}
```

Below is the error in console

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->com.idg.idgcore.BanksData["unknownFields"]->com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet["defaultInstanceForType"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1276) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter._handleSelfReference(BeanPropertyWriter.java:944) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:722) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContentsUsing(CollectionSerializer.java:171) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:116) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:400) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1510) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1006) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:454) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:290) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:219) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:124) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Any inputs will be helpful